# The name of the given podspec `EASClient` doesn't match the expected one `EASClient 2`

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, expo

After running expo update, I ran into this error. I've tried editing the `podsFile` but that lead no where. Any solution for this error would be helpful.

```
[!] The name of the given podspec `EASClient` doesn't match the expected one `EASClient 2`
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of pod files were corrupt so I ended up running `expo pre build`, which auto corrected the files for me. Then I just ran the pods again and it solved the issue.